# Converting Object to Time in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, jupyter

I have a dataset that containes a column with "Time" values, but it's showing as object, and I want to converte them to time so I can do a for loop to see if the time is between two times.

```
for i in df['Time']:
    if i >= dt.time(21,0,0) and i <= dt.time(7, 30,0) or i >= dt.time(3,0,0) and i <= dt.time(10,0,0) or i >= dt.time(10,30,0) and i <= dt.time(14,0,0):
        df['In/Out'] = 'In'
    else:
        df['In/Out'] = 'Out'
```

I want the code to set the value in a new column to "In" if the time is between two times.
The first times are (21:00) & (07:30) the second are (03:00) & (10:00) and the third are (10:30) & (14:00)

If the time is not in those ranges, it should set the value in the new column to "Out".

Comment: Please provide the minimal reproducible Data or you can post Dataframe in order to get you right advice. Meanwhile, you may try like  `df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])` or  `df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')`

Comment: this code worked for converting the time to (datetime64[ns]) ```df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')```, but the for-loop did give an error ```'>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify:

```
(21:00) & (07:30) the second are (03:00) & (10:00)
```

to:

```
(21:00) & (10:00)
```

so solution is use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['0:01:00','8:01:00','2021-08-13 10:19:10','12:01:00',
                        '14:01:00','18:01:01','23:01:00']})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time


m = (df['Time'].between(dt.time(21,0,0), dt.time(23,23,23)) | 
      df['Time'].between(dt.time(0,0,0), dt.time(10,0,0)) | 
      df['Time'].between(dt.time(10,30,0), dt.time(14, 0,0)))

df['In/Out'] = np.where(m, 'In','Out')
print (df)
       Time In/Out
0  00:01:00     In
1  08:01:00     In
2  10:19:10    Out
3  12:01:00     In
4  14:01:00    Out
5  18:01:01    Out
6  23:01:00     In
```

Comment: The times didn't work as expected. There is something wrong, and I couldn't find out what it is. The times between the onse in the code are saved as ```In``` where it should've said ```Out```.

Comment: @SoulSA - Can you be more specific? What times failed?

Comment: The time from 10am to 10:30am should be saved in dataset as ```out```, instead it's saved as ```in``` ... here is one data entry ``` 2021-08-13  10:19:10  In```

Comment: @SoulSA - tested ans for me working well, added changed data to answer.

Comment: ```m = (df['Time'].between(dt.time(21,0,0), dt.time(7,30,0)) | 
     df['Time'].between(dt.time(3,0,0), dt.time(10,0,0)) | 
     df['Time'].between(dt.time(10,30,0), dt.time(14,0,0)))

df['In/Out'] = np.where(m, 'Out','In')```

Comment: This is the code I use. I can't see the mistake in it.

Comment: @SoulSA - ya, there is problem with `df['Time'].between(dt.time(21,0,0), dt.time(7,30,0))`

Comment: @SoulSA - need `df['Time'].between(dt.time(21,0,0), dt.time(23,23,23)) | 
      df['Time'].between(dt.time(0,0,0), dt.time(7,30,0)) `